# Word 2013 - How do you delete a list of numbers at the side?

Tags: microsoft-word-2013, text-formatting

I have a Word 2013 document on my PC. I have opened a 36 page document (huge, word count more than 3300). I don't know why but there is a list of numbers on the left for each line. They are not suitable for printing. So, can someone please tell me how to remove them?

[image: 1]

Comment: I'd hardly describe 3300 as a "huge wordcount" for a 36-page document: that's less than 100 words per page. Your short question is already 55 words!

Comment: Copy and paste into a text file then open from excel with ,fixed with or delimited  then delete the column  then save it again in the document

Comment: @Omar sorry I can't understand. Copy the full document?

Comment: Yes into text file then open it from excel

Comment: if i do that, it puts everything in one column. So no use. :( But thanks cuz I did it the manual way.

Comment: Does the document have any formatting like bold, italics, different text sizes or colors?

Comment: no but I told u, i deleted the list manually! took half an hour but no probs.

Comment: Turning on the show special characters option before taking the screenshot might have helped to get answers better matched to your particular situation.

Answer (score 3):

1. Go to `Page Layout tab > Line Numbers > Line Numbering Options`:

   [image: 1]
2. Go to `Layout tab > click Line Numbers`:

   [image: 2]
3. Uncheck `Add line numbering` and OK your way out:

   [image: 3]

<sup><sup>[Source](http://www.howtogeek.com/170789/how-to-number-lines-in-the-margins-in-word-2013/)</sup></sup>

Comment: sorry, but I want to REMOVE them. :)And I already tried this technique, enabling and disabling, but no luck. So I guess, that is not part of this line numbering.But, I can delete them manually but there are so many it will take hell lot of time. Do you know how to select only these numbers? If I use the mouse or shift+ direction, it selects the text too.

Comment: Obviously you want to REMOVE them. That's why I said "**Uncheck** Add line numbering". :) If you already tried this you should really have mentioned it in the question itself. Anyway, try Alt+selecting the text with the mouse. Keeping Alt pressed allows you to select text in column mode, so you can try selecting the column with just the numbers and deleting it.

Answer (score 0):

Open the document in or copy it to a text editor with regex capabilities I am writing this with notepad++ in mind but it should work similarly with other editors. Open find&replace in the editor (probably strg+f). Make sure to enable regex matching. In the search field enter

```
\n\d+(?=\s)
```

if you only want to remove the numbers or

```
\n\d+\s+
```

if you also want to remove the whitespaces on the right of the numbers. In the replace field enter `\n`. 
Click `Replace all` and you should be done. You can try `Find all` first if you want to make sure that the regex actually works (I am not 100% sure and maybe you have some weird end-of-line characters).

Note: this only works if your document is just text and no sophisticated formatting like fonts and colors and bold and italics and all the other stuff you can do with word processors.